# Stable number of neutrons for a given nucleus with $Z$ protons

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, stability, protons, binding-energy

I have been trying to derive an expression for the stable number of neutrons using the [semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula). I tried to derive it by dividing the Ma by total number of nucleons and then derivating it w.r.t $A$ to get the expression for $A$ minimum. But I haven't been able to get a proper expression.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ? To derive $N/Z$ ratio from binding energy $E_B$ ?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get an expression for N, I got an equation for A, but I am unable to solve that particular equation.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where have you failed exactly ?

Comment: $-5.9 x^{5/3}-102.6 x^{2/3}+1016.4 x-22360.8=0$
I got this particular equation, and I am confused how to find the solution, I solved it using a graph, but I want to figure out how to do it numerically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a closed form solution to that equation. You can solve it numerically or use graphical methods as you mentioned. But I wouldn't expect a closed form soloution since this is based on the semi-empirical mass equation which is determined from various observations and not a physics-based expression.